# MYSQL Update find foreign key that match a condition and replace them foreign key that matches a different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a following tables

```
TAB_A
id | COUNTRY_ID | VAL
1  | 1   | val_x
2  | 1   | val_y
3  | 1   | val_z
4  | 2   | val_x
5  | 2   | val_y
6  | 2   | val_z
```

Tab_B.id_tab_A is currently store the id from TAB_A where `Ta_A.VAL = 'val_x' and Table_A.COUNTRY_ID = Table_B.COUNTRY_ID`. For example TAB_B(1,1,1) represent TABLE_B(id=1) => TABLE_A(1,1,val_x)

```
OLD TAB_B
id | COUNTRY_ID | id_tab_A
1  | 1   | 1
2  | 2   | 4
```

I want to replace all TAB_B.id_val_A such that:

```
if TAB_B.id_val_A  is equal to the id for TAB_A.VAL = 'val_x'   
it becomes id for TAB_A.VAL = 'val_x'
```

And course COUNTRY_ID also have to be equal

```
NEW TAB_B
id | COUNTRY_ID | id_tab_A
1  | 1   | 2
2  | 2   | 5
```

I can't use 2 queries as `COUNTRY_ID` are not fixed (can be anything etc. 3,4,5 in same other case):

```
UPDATE TAB_B tb, TAB_A ta
SET tb.id_tab_A = (SELECT ta.id FROM ta WHERE ta.COUNTRY_ID = 1 AND tb.VAL = 'val_y')
WHERE ta.VAL = 'val_x' AND ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID;

UPDATE TAB_B tb, TAB_A ta
SET tb.id_tab_A = (SELECT ta.id FROM ta WHERE ta.COUNTRY_ID = 1 AND tb.VAL = 'val_y')
WHERE ta.VAL = 'val_x' AND ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID;
```

I cant use:

```
UPDATE TAB_B tb, TAB_A ta
SET tb.id_tab_A = (SELECT ta.id FROM ta WHERE ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID AND tb.VAL = 'val_y')
WHERE ta.VAL = 'val_x' AND ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID;
```

as inner select `SELECT ta.id FROM ta WHERE ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID AND tb.VAL = 'val_y'` will more than one value.

Whats the right was to do above?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it's simply this update query:

```
UPDATE TabA ta
INNER JOIN TabB tb ON ta.COUNTRY_ID = tb.COUNTRY_ID AND ta.VAL = 'val_y'
SET tb.id_tab_A = ta.id;
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f7fd/1/0)</kbd>

You say, that this (you wrote the same just too complicated) can't be used, as it will return more than one value in your subquery. (Hint the future, reflect such cases in your sample data. Sample data is for testing all (edge) cases).
In that case, you obviously need more entries in `TabB` and a simple update won't work, except when you want to store multiple entries in one column. Don't do that, it's violating first normal form (read about normalization, if you don't know what I'm talking about).

Anyway, the big question given your small sample data is, why do you bother at all? The most logical thing to do, would be to merge those two tables. Whatever information else is stored in `TabB` is dependent on the key `country_id` which is redundant in `TabA`. My advice, rethink your database design.